# How to test if two lift values are significantly different from each other?

Tags: r, pst, traminer, significance, sequence-analysis

Consider this code:

```
# Load libraries
library(RCurl)
library(TraMineR)
library(PST)

# Get data
x <- getURL("https://gist.githubusercontent.com/aronlindberg/08228977353bf6dc2edb3ec121f54a29/raw/c2539d06771317c5f4c8d3a2052a73fc485a09c6/challenge_level.csv")
data <- read.csv(text = x)

# Load and transform data
data <- read.table("thread_level.csv", sep = ",", header = F, stringsAsFactors = F)

# Create sequence object
data.seq <- seqdef(data[2:nrow(data),2:ncol(data)], missing = NA, right= NA, nr = "*")

# Make a tree
S1 <- pstree(data.seq, ymin = 0.05, L = 6, lik = FALSE, with.missing = TRUE)

# Look at contexts
cmine(S1, pmin = 0, state = "N3", l = 3)
```

I can then calculate the significance thresholds for lift values for two particular "association rules" in the following manner:

```
# Calculate lift threshold for N2-QU->N3
ngood_idea <- sum(data.seq == "N3")
nn <- nrow(data.seq)*ncol(data.seq)
p_good_idea <- ngood_idea/nn

x <- seqdef("N2-QU")
p_context <- predict(S1, x, decomp = F, output = "prob")
p_not_context_good_idea <- (1-p_context)*(1-(p_good_idea))
p_context_good_idea <- p_context*p_good_idea
N2_QU_N3_threshold <- 1+1.645*sqrt(((1/nn)*(p_not_context_good_idea/p_context_good_idea)))

# Calculate lift threshold for N2-QU->N1
nbad_idea <- sum(data.seq == "N1")
nn <- nrow(data.seq)*ncol(data.seq)
p_bad_idea <- nbad_idea/nn

p_not_context_bad_idea <- (1-p_context)*(1-(p_bad_idea))
p_context_bad_idea <- p_context*p_bad_idea
N2_QU_N1_threshold <- 1+1.645*sqrt(((1/nn)*(p_not_context_bad_idea/p_context_bad_idea)))

# Print lift thresholds
N2_QU_N3_threshold
N2_QU_N1_threshold
```

However, what if I want to compare two lift values with each other, to see if they are significantly different from each other (in a manner similar to how I can compare two regression coefficients to each other to see if they are significantly different from each other)? How can I accomplish this?

Comment: If you're looking for a statistical test to compare two numbers, you should be asking over at [stats.se]; this is not a specific programming question. There are different tests based on different assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizing this equation:

```
$Z = \frac{\beta_1-\beta_2}{\sqrt{(SE\beta_1)^2+(SE\beta_2)^2}}$
```

Where `$SE\beta$` is the standard error of `$\beta$`.

This equation is provided by Clogg et al (1995)

Source: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93540/testing-equality-of-coefficients-from-two-different-regressions

We can analogize, using the lifts as the coefficients, and the calculation of the variance of each lift based on Lenca et al (2008, p. 619)

```
# Calculate conditional probability for I3
cp_good <- query(S1, context = "N2-QU", output= "prob")@.Data[attr(query(S1, context = "N2-QU", output= "prob")@.Data, "dimnames")[[2]]=="I3"]
cp_good <- unlist(cp_good)

# Calculate conditional probability for I1
cp_bad <- query(S1, context = "N2-QU", output= "prob")@.Data[attr(query(S1, context = "N2-QU", output= "prob")@.Data, "dimnames")[[2]]=="I1"]
cp_bad <- unlist(cp_bad)

# Calculate lift for I3
ngood_idea <- sum(data.seq == "I3")
nn <- nrow(data.seq)*ncol(data.seq)
p_good_idea <- ngood_idea/nn

good_lift <- cp_good/p_good_idea

# Calculate lift for I1
nbad_idea <- sum(data.seq == "I1")
nn <- nrow(data.seq)*ncol(data.seq)
p_bad_idea <- nbad_idea/nn

bad_lift <- cp_bad/p_bad_idea

# Calculate z_diff
p_context <- predict(S1, x, decomp = F, output = "prob")

p_not_context_good_idea <- (1-p_context)*(1-(p_good_idea))
p_context_good_idea <- p_context*p_good_idea

p_not_context_bad_idea <- (1-p_context)*(1-(p_bad_idea))
p_context_bad_idea <- p_context*p_bad_idea

var_good_idea <- ((1/nn)*(p_not_context_good_idea/p_context_good_idea))
var_bad_idea <- ((1/nn)*(p_not_context_bad_idea/p_context_bad_idea))

z_diff <- (good_lift-bad_lift)/sqrt(var_good_idea+var_bad_idea)
z_diff
```

The z-value of the difference is `0.2556881`.

#### References

Clogg, C. C., Petkova, E., & Haritou, A. (1995). Statistical methods for comparing regression coefficients between models. *American Journal of Sociology*, *100*(5), 1261-1293.]

Lenca, P., Meyer, P., Vaillant, B., and Lallich, S. 2008. “On selecting interestingness measures for association rules: User oriented description and multiple criteria decision aid,” European Journal of Operational Research (184:2), pp. 610–626 (doi: 10.1016/j.ejor.2006.10.059).